How can I make a python window allow itself to be recorded, when part of it is off-screen?
In windows 10, most application windows can be recorded using a program like OBS.
When the window is dragged such that part of it is not visible on the display, typically, OBS will still receive the content of the window, even if it is not visible on the screen.
However, when programming a python application, this appears to not work the same way.
I've tried several different GUI-like modules for testing, for example, PyQt6, pygame, tkinter, and pyglet.
The following code just creates a window that flashes black and white.
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
window.show()

def toggle_color():
    current_color = window.styleSheet()
    new_color = "background-color: black;" if current_color == "background-color: white;" else "background-color: white;"
    window.setStyleSheet(new_color)

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(toggle_color)
timer.start(500)

app.exec()

When this code runs, and the window is recorded, and part of the window is dragged off-screen, it creates screen tears, and any part of the window that is offscreen does not update.

I initially thought it was due to the modules itself, and the way they handle windows, but now I believe this is a much more fundamental issue with the way python creates windows and sends data.
My question essentially is if there is any way to change the nature of this such that the entirety of windows python creates can be recorded, offscreen or not (similar to most other programs).

Have you tried other modules, e.g. pygame, and checked if the problem is not only with pyqt?

Yes, I have tried pygame, as well as tkinter and pyglet. If there are any others you think I should try let me know, but at this point I am fairly convinced it is either something intrinsic to Python, or something that these modules all have in common.

This is really interesting. I would assume, python shouldn't be related to this, but more likr the underlying graphics framework that is responsible for the window. But these libraries have different graphics backends, e.g. SDL or OpenGL, which are used in many programs outside of python.

Perhaps it's worth investigating why most programs behave differently? Every program I have installed on my computer that I've tested has behaved the exact same way as for example chrome, where it allows OBS to record the content of the window when it is clipping off the screen.

Are you saying that if you don't use the timer to call toggle_color(), the problem doesn't exist? This seems strange, but probably not impossible. Yet, I sincerely doubt that this has anything to do with Python, as the only effect it could have would be to shortly block the event loop more than it normally would while using the pure C++ implementation. In fact, programmatically speaking, Qt has absolutely no awareness of Python, therefore its behavior is not affected by it, except for the possible bottleneck Python introduces when calling its own instructions.

No, it doesn't matter what is used to call toggle_color, updating the contents of the window in any way, does not update the contents of the part of the window that is offscreen.
I don't even know what to call the phenomenon I am looking for, perhaps "offscreen rendering" or something? However searches for stuff like this yields results that seem very unrelated.
As for the fact that Qt has no awareness of python, I understand, however I have not found any python library that can produce the phenomenon in a window that I previously described, so I don't think it is specific to QT

@frozenwall The point is, if you don't call toggle_color() at all (or any function called in there, even externally), does the issue still reproduce? I think so, so it probably depends on how the graphics toolkit reacts with the OS graphics and internal buffering and how OBS actually works with the underlying graphics system to grab the contents of a window. AFAIK, on Linux, nothing existing outside the screen geometry will be captured, it may work differently on other systems, but it also depends on how the program's toolkit works with the graphics system and the drawing buffer.

@frozenwall It's quite possible that some toolkits render the whole contents even if outside of the screen geometry, while others (like, supposedly, Qt on your OS) just don't and only repaint what actually shown on the screen upon resizing, and for optimization reasons. Shortly put, there's probably nothing you can do about it. (please remember to use @username when more than 2 people are interacting in comments)
